# Could not find stored procedure 'ELMAH_GetErrorsXml'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, elmah

I've installed Elmah.MVC nuget to my web application and got it up and running. I am able to see the error log when I have this xml tag `<errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />`in my `<elmah></elmah>`.

What I am trying to do is log the errors in a SQL Server database, so I added this line `<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ElmahConnection" />` and removed the old one. The `ElmahConnection` connection string points to an existing database in which I have successfully managed to create the table that Elmah requires and it has the stored procedures and everything. But when I try to access a non-existing page there are no logs in the table and when trying to reach `/elmah.axd` I get this

> Could not find stored procedure 'ELMAH_GetErrorsXml'.

Comment: What SQL user is your web application using? Does that user have permission to those stored procedures?

Comment: It uses system admin(sa) user

Comment: How can i check for permissions?

Comment: Well that is kind of scary from a permissions/security standpoint. But for your issue at hand...  Maybe give this link a try http://www.yangsoft.com/blog/?p=214   Sounds like they resolved the issue by running the proper schema install script again

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to get it working by creating a new database and executing this script to it --> [script](http://pastebin.com/n2hMGBsk). After that I granted my user permissions over that database.

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore - Google's downloads appear to be broken. Anywhere else I can get this?

Comment: hello @qJake I've managed to find the script on my disk so I've uploaded it to `pastebin`. See the updated link in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It warns me about the compatibility of the database although it is logging the values correctly.

Answer (score 2):

My database objects were lost. I had to rerun the scripts to recreate the database objects and stored procedure. Older Google Doc links did not work, but found them here for version 1.2: https://elmah.github.io/downloads/